# Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly (mvn clean package -DskipTest)

Tags: java, maven, jvm, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to command line and Ubuntu.

I am trying to run this:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTest
```

as indicated on this site: 
https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/

I opened up Command line and typed.

I am getting error message:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-oracle/bin/java
```

Any lead would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: What is your `JAVA_HOME` variable set to (`echo $JAVA_HOME`)?

Comment: /usr/lib/jvm/java-oracle

Comment: Is there a Java JDK there?

Comment: I have severals (....java-7-openjdk-amd64, java-7-oracle, java-8-oracle) Sorry I am so new to this stuff.

Comment: I have severals (java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386, java-7-openjdk-i386, java-6-openjdk-amd64, java-7-openjdk-amd64, java-7-oracle, java-8-oracle) Sorry I am so new to this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
```

Show you that JDK isn't installed correctly, you should reinstall JDK, see [OpenJDK page](http://openjdk.java.net/install/), you can try to use following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: I tried your command line. It says "Package openjdk-08-jre is a virtual package provided by:  oracle-java9-installer 9b175-1~webupd8~0   oracle-java8-installer 8u131-1~webupd8~2   You should explicitly select on eto install   E: Package 'openjdk-8-jre' has no installation candidate

Comment: Isn't it   sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre instead of sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk  ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export JAVA_HOME
```

You can also set it in /etc/environment or ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile etc. But check which version is installed on your system.

Or you download the JDK as tar, unpack it in your home and use that jdk (allwoes to have different versions installed and easy switching those).